# ngAnimate animations not showing

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

I was trying for the past 10 hours to make the animations work, and they only work when i add animate.css stylesheet and use "animated classname", but when i want to make custom animations for enter and leave i cant make it to work anyhow.

here is simple plunkr from my code, I've also tried with different versions of ngAnimate, still nothing.

[PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/2inz8LhZXLrBB8MWX1NB?p=preview)
Also I tried adding "animation: animationname", still cant make it to work

```
  .ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-animation: bounceIn 2.5s;
    animation: bounceIn 2.5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the version of angular and angular-animate. I changed everything to 1.4.0 and everything is fine now